# What is the term that describes the "user" of a status ailment

Tags: terminology

Suppose a Snake performs a skill that inflicts a "poison" status on the Hero, and every minute the Hero receives damage equal to the Snake's skill level.

What is a term that would describe the snake as the object that inflicted the status ailment, that players would recognize or be able to figure out based on context? I imagine there are some standard terminology used in the industry.

Some things I have thought of include "applier" or "inflicter".

Comment: Enemy is a really general term. A mob is commonly used name in mmos and rpgs for enemies. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No, though it seems you might have posted in the wrong question. The term I am looking for is independent of who the user is (Hero could have applied the status to the snake and the same term would be used to describe the Hero)

Comment: Then how about "caster" as in skill/spell caster, or if you are looking for a more general name, only thing that comes in my mind that fits both players and mobs is "character". Or maybe even "entity".

Comment: "Caster" might work. Does the following statement sound intuitive: "The poison status' caster", which means the caster (ie: the snake) inflicted the poison status.

Comment: The snake is the "cause" or "source" of the ailment. That's what I'd use to show when the player hovers over the ailment's icon, for example.

Comment: I like those suggestions. I will probably use "cause" as I could then use the word "caused" to describe an action that occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_effect

According to the above, one can glean the following:

1. a positive effect is a Buff
2. a negative effect is a Debuff
3. the recipient of either is the Target
4. the source of either is the Caster

Ergo, the poison effect would be a Debuff with the Snake as the Caster and the Player as the Target